# Power form of regression equation which is not centered at x=0?

Tags: graphing-functions, regression, regression-analysis

For a given set of data, the power form of the regression equation is given by
$$y=b\cdot x^{m}$$
where
$$m=\frac{n(\sum \mathrm{ln}(x_i)\mathrm{ln}(y_i))-(\sum \mathrm{ln}(x_i))(\sum \mathrm{ln}(y_i))}{n(\sum (\mathrm{ln}(x_i))^2)-(\sum \mathrm{ln}(x_i))^2}$$
$$\textrm{ln}(b)=\frac{\sum \textrm{ln}(y_i)-m(\sum \textrm{ln}(x_i))}{n}$$

However, the resulting equation $y=b\cdot x^{m}$ is centered at $x=0$. My question is, how should this method be modified so that the whole graph shift a certain $c$ units to the right along the x-axis instead of centered at $x=0$? In other words, the form of the equation should be:

$$y=b\cdot (x-c)^{m}$$

---

So for the data below (black dots), for example, instead of getting this (centered at $x=0$, $y\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$):

[image: graph 1]

I should get a regression line like (centered at $x<0$, y-intercept exists as $x=0$):

[image: graph 2]

Comment: Have you thought of conducting a linear regression of $\log y$ on $\log (x-c)$?

Comment: @Dr. MV: In my case I don't know the value of c. So I'm asking is it possible to get a regression equation with the form $b\cdot (x-c)^{m}$ instead of $b\cdot (x)^{m}$

Comment: Yes.  There are methodologies for fitting a shifted power law relationship.

Comment: @Dr.MV. Could you tell more ? I am very interested but did not find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  You need to develop, or have access to, a routine that can find the "best fit" of the shifted power law.  The "best fit" can be a least squares fit, for example.  The routine then finds the parameters that minimizes the sum of the squared differences between the actual data and the parameterized curve.  Make sense?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Here is a website that describes the lists various Regression types. Note the 3rd Bullet Point under the Power Law Family category.   Best sincere wishes!    http://www.curveexpert.net/products/curveexpert-basic/23-2/

Comment: @Dr.MV. This does not give any indication about the algorithm. Do you know some method other than the trial-and-error method I proposed in my answer ?

Comment: Are you asking about search global searcg algorithms such as simulated annealing or genetic algorithms?

Comment: @sniperkit2en : Possibly, a straightforward method could be proposed to solve your problem. This method doesn't requires initial guess, nor iterative or "trial and error" process. Unfortunately, from the figure that you published, it is not possible to obtain sufficently accurate points in order to test and decide if the method is convenient, or not, in your specific case. Could you provide  the data on numerical form ?

Comment: Could you post the values of the data points used in your graph ? I would like to play with them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part, in order to fit the data to $y=b\, x^m$, you linearize the model to get $\log(y)=\beta=m\log(x)$ which corresponds to a linear regression. But, this gives you estimates of the parameters. From this points, you need to continue with nonlinear regression since what you want to minimize is the sum of the squared errors for the $y$'s and not for the $\log(y)$'s.

For the problem where the model is $$y=b\,(x-c)^m$$ what you could notice is that, if $c$ was known, it would be the same problem as before. So, fix $c$ to a given value, make the logarithmic transform and compute $SSQ(c)$ since the resulting values of $\beta$ and $m$ depend on $c$; plotting the function will show you an approximate value of the $c$ which minimizes $SSQ(c)$.

What this is done, you have all elements for starting the nonlinear regression with the three adjustable parameters.

**Edit**

For illustration purposes, I generated a table of $25$ data points $(x_i=i+20\, , i=1$ to $20)$ with $$y_i=12.34 (x-15.27)^{-0.345}+0.2 (-1)^i$$ and I did what was described above fixing successively $c$ to $0,1,\cdots,24$ (remember than $c$ cannot be larger than the smallest of the $x_i$'s because of the exponentiation. For the linearized model, the sum of squares is a quite flat function of $c$ but it goes through a minimum for $c=14$ (at this point, $\log(b)=2.637$ and $m=-0.379$). Now, we can start the nonlinear regression which leads to $b=14.392$, $c=13.692$, $m=-0.3866$.

Comment: Hi Claude !  Your approach is interresting on the practical viewpoint. I would like only to make a point of small importance  : In your example, you set a positive value of $c=15.27$. Then $x$ cannot be lower that this value. The curve $y(x)$ cannot be drawn in the range from $x=0$ to higher values, as wanted by sniperkit2en (his second grath) who is expecting a negative value of $c$.

Comment: I totally agree with you ! I wanted to ask you (and this is a good apportunity) if you worked this problem for a non-iterative approximate solution. As the OP and you point out, it is not as simple as it looks at first glance when the data points are so far from the origin. I even wonder what would the significance of statistical tests for the points used here. I shall ask the OP the data. Cheers.

Comment: @JJacquelin. I wrote a reply to your comment forgetting to put $@JJacquelin$ in front.

Comment: I also doubt of the significance of the fitted function extrapolated so far from the experimental points (except if the scatter is very small). That is why I didn't propose the non-iterative method without doing a premilinary test.